# calling method on top-level react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  handleFoo: function() {
    self.setState(...);
  },
  ...
})
```

I render it with:

```
var top = ReactDOM.Render(<Main />, document.getElementById("x"))
```

And then later I receive data from an external source and I want to interact with the top-level component, so I tried:

```
top.handleFoo()
```

But I get

```
TypeError: top.handleFoo is not a function
```

What is the right way to interact with the top-level react component from outside of the component hierarchy?

Comment: I think your syntax is correct. What do you get when you `console.log(top.__proto__)`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Passing data to React is usually done using `props`:

```
var data = /* get your data from this external source */
ReactDOM.Render(<Main mydata={data} />, document.getElementById("x"))
```

Here we getting some data, and passing it to our Main component as a prop named `mydata`.

From our component we can use the props we recieved like this:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  handleFoo: function() {
    var mydata = this.props.mydata;
    /* do what you want with data */
    self.setState(...);
  },
  ...
})
```

Please note that if you want to update the data you pass to `Main`, you would have to render it again, if you want to avoid that you can either fetch the data from withing the component, or manage your application state using `redux` and `react-redux`.

Is there any reason why you don't fetch the data from within the component itself?

Comment: The reason I don't fetch the data from within the component is that I am working with electron and I am trying to respond to an event from a native menu item. The reason I want to call a method on my react element is that I have the top-level element maintaining most of the state at the moment, and if I move to using props then I have to move all the state out of the top-level component and into free functions, which seems like overkill. The specific use case is calling "handleNew", which will create a new note in the root components state.notes.

Comment: I see. Well as far as I know (and I may be wrong), react doesn't offer option to do so: communication from parent components to their children can be done via props, communication from children to parent can be done using a parent function which is passed to the children via props.
For something else, usually the solution is `redux` - a great and simple javascript library for managing application state, which can be hooked into react components using the helper library `react-redux`. I think this is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Any state changes should be made within the component. External components which interact with the class are of two types: Parent and Peer. Parent components can change state via sending new props. Peer components should change state using events.